# Integrated Webcam Stopped Working Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: skype, webcam, cheese

I've been on Ubuntu 14 for maybe 2 months. When I first installed it I was on unity until I switched to `gnome`, and then I removed `unity`, `lightdm`, and `gnome` and now I use `i3wm`.

My built in webcam worked perfectly fine when I had `i3wm` installed beside `lightdm` and unity, and I believe it even worked after I removed `unity` and `lightdm` for a while, but I'm not sure what happened. I assume I removed something critical.

I'm using an Inspiron N5110. Cheese outputs a black box saying "No device found". Same with Skype. If I try to visit a site like omegle flash crashes.

I also tried plugging in a usb webcam that worked previously on this same install and it didn't work, so I'm doubting that it's a hardware problem

Output of lsusb:

```
~ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0c45:6483 Microdia 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of dmesg|grep uvcvideo

```
~ dmesg|grep uvcvideo
[   21.718907] uvcvideo: Found UVC 1.00 device Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:6483)
[   21.985380] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Edit: After messing around with some things it seems like it's a permissions problem. If I sudo guvcview or sudo cheese, my webcam will run properly. Both will. But only if I sudo.

Any advice?

Comment: Similar problems but sudo does not work for me. However, I have had all working properly in ubuntu 14.04 32 bit, it seems that 64 bit is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Install the webcam drivers containing packages:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

If they are already installed, then reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` && sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Hmm, doesnt seem like it worked